# Should I mock AR associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, activerecord

I'm trying to test my **Order** AR model in "isolation", but because it lives into a complex "context", I need to create a lot of associated AR models before.

My models are:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :registration #it's required!!!
end

class Registration < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event #it's required!!!
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :registrations
  belongs_to :account #An account belongs_to an organization

  #This model a couple of required associations also
end
```

Is some way to "mock" the associations of my **Order** model??? Should I?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If an Order needs to have a Registration in order for it to work as inteded, then yes, you need to create a Registration and associate it to Order before you can test, otherwise what's the point of testing a Order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that with proper factory_girl setup, there will be absolutely no issues to easily setup context, that you need. During my experience I haven't faced any cases when associations were stubbed.

From my point of view, if you have some complex method inside your Order model, then you should move it into separate entity (service object, separate library, decorator). Then you can easily test this logic, without any need to setup associations, objects, etc.

I don't remember the last time I really needed to test my modal in isolation after I start making correct design of my application. I suspect, that your issue is also like a bell for you about your design. I treat models only as a set of validations(tested inside rails), associations(tested inside rails) and trivial methods, so usually there is no need to test your models

Comment: Thanks Anton for your reply. Finally, I followed that you recommended: I used factory_girl to setup the complex context that spec required.